# TypeError: d is undefined in OBIEE11g

Tags: obiee

I want to use single button for different prompt in OBIEE 11g.
I wrote this code in text:

```
<DIV CLASS = "XUIPromptEntry minibuttonOn">
<input class="button" type = "button" value = "Apply" onclick='javascript:
    try
    {
        var x = 0;
        var aElm=PromptManager.getPromptManager().getAllPromptCollectionJSON();
        for(var i = 0; i < aElm.length;i ++ )
                    {
                    for(var j = 0; j < aElm[i].promptSteps[0].prompts.length;j ++ )
                                {
                                var promptid = aElm[i].promptSteps[0].prompts[j].promptStreamID;
                                var g = null;
                                var h = PromptManager.getPromptManager().getPromptCollectionInfoWithViewID(aElm[i].viewStatePath);
                                if(h)
                                            {
                                            try
                                                        {
                                                        var b = h.getAllPromptExprsArray();
                                                        if( ! h.verifyPromptValuesAndDisplayError(b))
                                                                    {
                                                                    return;
                                                                    }
                                                        g = PromptManager.buildPromptExprGivenExpr("", b);
                                                        }
                                            catch(f)
                                                        {
                                                        alert(f);
                                                        return;
                                                        }
                                            }
                                }
                    x++;
                    }
        x--;
        PromptManager.submitPrompt(aElm[x].viewStatePath, true,"PromptFinish", g)
    }
    catch(e) {alert("Apply ALL Button Exception" + e.description);}' ></input> 
<input class="button" type = "button"  value = "Clear" ONCLICK = 'return PersonalizationEditor.removeDefaultSelection(false)' > </input>
<div/>
```

but I get this error:
TypeError: d is undefined

Answer (score 0):

try to comment this part of code

```
if( ! h.verifyPromptValuesAndDisplayError(b))                                                                   
{ return; }
```